# How can users take part in sorting of articles that need changes in a website?

Tags: feedback

For a portal that houses thousands of articles and posts, how can users take a part in the entire process of marking what posts and articles need changes?

A lot of posts can be helped with valuable feedback and moderators-only approach seems ineffective.

One thing is upvotes and downvotes, but they don't serve the purpose here as they don't tell what exactly is wrong. Similarly, score feedbacks would just tell me that some article is wrong somewhere, nothing else.

Without getting confused or irritated, how can a user seamlessly take part in this entire process of assorting out of posts that might need changes?

Comment: Is sounds like you're describing a wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Matt commented it seems like wiki. But if you don't want to allow user to edit text you may allow him to comment text or mark it. Here is some possible ways to implement this:

1. User can mark a piece of text using cursor like during copy/paste and then press Comment button (icon, context menu, etc.). Then write a comment in comment window and save it.
2. Article text is divided to some numbered pieces - paragraphs, lines, etc. Each item has checkbox allowing to mark it as requiring attention and/or button to open textbox to leave a comment.

Instead of textbox for arbitrary comments or single checkbox for marking you may provide radio button set for selecting some predefined comment or mark, or dropdown list for the same purpose, or slider for setting rating, etc.

Comment: After writing this answer I found great illustration of one of possible solutions mentioned. It is so nice that I place this link with please (not affiliated) - https://medium.com/@lucabenazzi/the-tyranny-of-testing-over-design-a4ea5be352a6